# What's the read logic when I call recvfrom() function in C/C++

Tags: sockets, udp, recv, icmp, recvfrom

I wrote a C++ program to create a socket and bind on this socket to receive ICMP/UDP packets. The code I wrote as following:

```
while(true){
   recvfrom(sockId, rePack, sizeof(rePack), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&raddr, (socklen_t *)&len);
   processPakcet(recv_size);
}
```

So, I used a endless while loop to receive messages continually, But I worried about the following two questions:

```
1, How long the message would be kept in the receiver queue or say in NIC queue?
```

I worried about that if it takes too long to process the first message, then I might miss the second message. so how fast should I read after read.

`2, How to prevent reading the duplicated messages?`

i.e, does the receiver queue knows me, when my thread read the first message done, would the queue automatically give me the second one? or say, when I read the first message, then the first message would be deleted by the queue and no one could receive it again.

Additionally, I think the while(true) module is not good, anyone could give me a good suggestion please. (I heard something like polling module).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should always check the return value from `recvfrom`. It's unlikely the `recvfrom` will fail, but if it does (for example, if you later implement signal handling, it might fail with `EINTR`) you will be processing undefined data. Also, of course, the return value tells you the size of the packet you received.

For question 1, the actual answer is operating system-dependent. However, most operating systems will buffer some number of packets for you. The OS interrupt handler that handles the incoming packet will never be copying it directly into your application level buffer, so it will always go into an OS buffer first. The OS has previously noted your interest in it (by virtue of creating the socket and binding it you expressed interest), so it will then place a pointer to the buffer onto a queue associated with your socket.

A different part of the OS code will then (after the interrupt handler has completed) copy the data from the OS buffer into your application memory, free the OS buffer, and return to your program from the `recvfrom` system call. If additional packets come in, either before or after you have started processing the first one, they'll be placed on the queue too.

That queue is not infinite of course. It's likely that you can configure how many packets (or how much buffer space) can be reserved, either at a system-wide level (think `sysctl`-type settings in linux), or at the individual socket level (`setsockopt` / `ioctl`).

If, when you call `recvfrom`, there are already queued packets on the socket, the system call handler will not *block* your process, instead it will simply copy from the OS buffer of the next queued packet into your buffer, release the OS buffer, and return immediately. As long as you can process incoming packets roughly as fast as they arrive or faster, you should not lose any. (However, note that if another system is generating packets at a very high rate, it's likely that the OS memory reserved *will* be exhausted at some point, after which the OS will simply discard packets that exceed its resource reservation.)

For question 2, you will receive no duplicate messages (unless something upstream of your machine is actually duplicating them). Once a queued message is copied into your buffer, it's released before returning to you. That message is gone forever.

(Note that it's possible that some other process has also created a socket expressing interest in the same packets. That process would also get a copy of the packet data, which is typically handled internal to the operating system by reference counting rather than by actually duplicating the OS buffers, although that detail is invisible to applications. In any case, once all interested processes have received the packet, it will be discarded.)

There's really nothing at all wrong with a `while (true)` loop; it's a very common control structure for long-running server-type programs. If your program has nothing else it needs to be doing in the meantime, `while true` allowing it to block in `recvfrom` is the simplest and hence clearest way to implement it.

(You could use a `select(2)` or `poll(2)` call to wait. This allows you to handle waiting for any one of multiple file descriptors at the same time, or to periodically "time out" and go do something else, say, but again if you have nothing else you might need to be doing in the meantime, that is introducing needless complication.)

Comment: Note that it is possible to receive duplicate UDP messages (I.e. UDP makes no guarantees that it won’t happen), although it’s unusual for that to happen unless there are redundant networking paths between sender and receiver.